# What's the benefit of having pi and sigma types with an invariant parameter?

Tags: agda, subtyping, type-rule

Ulf Norell wrote this in his PhD thesis (figure 1.6):

[image]

This contradicts my stereotype on pi & sigma types, where pi parameter should be contravariant and sigma parameter is covariant. Why is Agda designed this way? Is it actually implemented this way?

P.S. I have two guesses why pi has invariant parameter:

0. That contravariant parameter makes the type theory complex, because you keep track of the actual type and the type in the telescope -- two types -- of a binding. Without contravariant pi parameter we can think of them as the same thing.
1. According to [Conor McBride](https://pigworker.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/universe-hierarchies), it's Zhaohui Luo's Extended CoC that made this design choice for a simpler set-theoretical semantics (that subtyping is modelled by subsetting).

Which of these is true? Or are they both unrelated to the Agda design choice?

Comment: If `A1` is **not** equivalent to `A2` then the whole thing becomes _very_ confusing to me. AFAIU the marked rules assume that `B1` depends on `x : A1` while `B2` depends on `x : A2`. Now if `A1` and `A2` are _different_ types how can we compare `B1` and `B2` at all? In particular, what needs to be added to the context `x : A1` or `x : A2` to even correctly construct _both_ `B1` and `B2` to compare them?

Comment: I believe the only reason for this is indeed the desire to have subtyping modeled by "material subsets" in a set theoretic model. As this is not a particularly rational basis for the design of a type theory (subsets are an encoding artifact), I would not expect to see this decision in new / present-day formulations of type theory.

Comment: @Alex Chichigin If you have the subsumption law (or coercions), there is definitely no problem with A1 being different from A2. Suppose that `B1 : A1 -> Type` and `B2 : A2 -> Type` such that `A1 <= A2`. Then in the context `x : A1 |-` we can easily compare `B1(x) <= B2(x)` because `x:A1` is coerced to an element of `A2`. So there is no problem here.

Comment: @JonathanSterling on that level yeah, "no problem", though one better have `A2 ≤ A1` for contravariance. :) But the perspective to have a function type that's a subtype of another function type _only on a subset of its domain_ is still puzzling and a bit unnerving to me. :D

Comment: Yes, I was speaking about the dependent sums; for the dependent product, it is indeed the other way around.

But I don't see why it is puzzling and unnerving --- to me, the semantics for subtyping is simply a *distinguished* injective function. And when you have an injective function `i : A2 >-> A1` and a family of injective functions `jx : B1(ix) >-> B2x` then there is an obvious injective function `Pi(A1,B1) >-> Pi(A2,B2)`. I find it hard to understand what can be more natural than this...

Comment: It is true that some find contravariance in general to be unnerving, but that is not about function types...

Comment: @JonathanSterling newer thought about it as an injective function! That's an illuminating perspective indeed. Thanks! :D

Comment: Glad you find it illuminating! :) To me the prototype is `Nat >-> Int` and all the rest flows from there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are subtleties here, when type annotations are present, depending in quite a brittle way on where they must be placed. (I'm half-remembering conversations about this with Zhaohui Luo.) Suppose we demand (as many do) type annotations on lambda, with a typing rule like this

```
S : Type_i     x : S |- t : T
-----------------------------
\ x : S -> t  :  (x : S) -> T
```

In particular, we may readily have

```
\ X : Type_1 -> X : (X : Type_1) -> Type_1
```

Now, if cumulativity were contravariant in the input type, we should allow

```
(X : Type_1) -> Type_1  <=  (X : Type_0) -> Type_1
```

and, indeed, one might imagine that the identity function for `Type_1` should work perfectly well for those of its inhabitants which happen also to live in `Type_0`. But there's a snag, if you want cumulativity to be, in a suitable sense, reducible to universe inclusion. The typing rule for lambda will only ever give

```
\ X : Type_1 -> X
```

function types with the domain `Type_1`, because that is what the domain type annotation says, and we're stuck with it. There is a function that does thejob we want, but it's

```
\ X : Type_0 -> X
```

and that ain't the function we first thought of.

Now, if you're me, you arrange never to *synthesize* the types of lambda abstractions, only to *check* them, removing the need for the type annotation. Then, both `Type_0 -> Type_1` and `Type_1 -> Type_1` will accept `\ X -> X`. In the bidirectional setting, the "change of direction" rule says that to check that `T` accepts a term whose synthesized type is `S`, then an `S` thing should be able to do all a `T` thing's jobs. That clear directedness yields great temptation to relax from equality to a subsumptive notion of subtyping, and in that setting contravariance in function domains is not a problem.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments already, even if you do allow for cumulativity (in one direction or the other) in your domain type, you do not need to record the two types in your context: only the smaller one is enough, as a variable of that type can be considered at the larger one by means of subtyping. So your point 0 is not really an issue.

My personal understanding is indeed your point 1: most theoretical study of (implicit) cumulativity was done with set-theoretic models. This is the case of ECC, but also of the more recent line of work by Werner, and the papers by Sozeau and Timany on cumulative inductive types (which are implemented in Coq). All those set-theoretic models interpret cumulativity by inclusion, and this works well with covariant codomains, but does not play nicely with contravariant (in the case of products) or covariant (in the case of sigma) domains. The issue is that if you have $A' \subseteq A$ and $B \subseteq B'$, then a functional relation $R \subseteq A \times B$ is also a functional relation on $A \times B'$, but it is *not* a relation on $A' \times B'$, because for that you would need to remove elements of $R$ (those pairs where the first component is not in $A'$). Note that this is not even linked with dependency, it would already come up with non-dependent function types.

As Jonathan Sterling points out in the comments, there is another way to understand cumulativity, namely as the existence of (nicely behaved) coercions from one type to the other. With this point of view (which I feel is also in line with how people from the programming language world understand subtyping), cumulativity could be made contravariant on product types. However, I am not aware of any work trying to tackle the details of such a model. I see no reason for it not to work, but someone has to bite the bullet…
[Edit: It seems I spoke too fast and overlooked work in the area, see the comments by András Kovács and Jonathan Sterling in the comments, all my excuses to them!]

Comment: I briefly wrote about contravariant cumulative subtyping in section 5.2 [here](https://cs.emis.de/LIPIcs/volltexte/2022/15748/pdf/LIPIcs-CSL-2022-28_.pdf). I really didn't elaborate this, but the point is that contravariance is wholly straightforward in inductive-recursive semantics of cumulativity.

Comment: Many thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Regarding biting the bullet, much of my work in the past three years does this. For a consolidated location, see my [thesis](https://www.jonmsterling.com/abstracts.html#sterling:2021:thesis) which describes the cumulativity laws algebraically in terms of certain monomorphisms; this frees me in models to implement the coercions however I like, which is really necessary.

But I don't claim novelty: that is because I do not think there was any non-trivial work needed to execute "coercions as monomorphisms", which has been the established categorical understanding of subtyping for decades.

Comment: I have hard time understanding the heavily categorical approach to those, so I missed that one, sorry about it – and thanks for the pointer! So you say that this is a good account of "implicit" cumulativity, and that we should leave these set-models of ECC behind and go look at your work instead? Do you think this is enough of a justification for adopting contravariant cumulativity in eg. Coq? Or are there some annoying twists?